# "Invalid provider type specified" when signing clickonce manifest in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce, vsto, code-signing, pfx

I have a certificate issued by a CA on our intranet (it's a V3 sha1 pfx file).

When I use this in the signing part of my clickonce (vsto addin) project, I get the error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Office2007.targets(250,9): error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Invalid provider type specified.
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the V3 certificate issued by out Windows 2008 CA was too advanced for my humble .Net 2.0 VS2008 installation... the solution for me was to get out CA to issue a Windows 2003 compatible version of the certificate, and hey-presto, I can use it to sign my lovely cruddy code!